# fatal signal 4 SIGILL, no idea of what is happening with eclipse and cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, stack, cocos2d-x, trace

I get an error on my game developed with cocos2d-x and eclipse.

I get an error "Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x51947ffc  (code=1)"

I have no idea what is happening, there's any stack trace that I can see fore more information about what type of error is happening?

Comment: Your program is crashing because it tried to execute an illegal instruction. Most likely that's incorrect code damaged the contents of program memory. The only way to find out what's happening is to run the program inside a debugger, step through the crash, and inspect the state of the program; generally this will let you figure out the cause of the crash. There's really nothing anyone else here can tell you.

Comment: Typically, you get this error when the code "falls over the edge of the earth" - that is, when you jump to something that isn't actually code (such as text or data). You can also get it if you have the wrong combination between actual model of processor you run on, and the one you told the compiler to generate code for (e.g. asking for SSE3 code on a processor that doesn't have SSE3)

Comment: I discover the problem. I run my game in two devices, a Xperia Mini pro and a Galaxy Pocket Plus, when I run the game on the Xperia, the game runs fine, but when I run the game on Galaxy Pocket, the game crash. The problem is that Galaxy Pocket only accept images that have a maximum of 2048px of width or heigth. Since my image is bigger than that, the game crash when it opens. I resolved the problem by divide the image in two images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this blog http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2013/08/23/catching-posix-signals-on-android/

Maybe it can help you.